# yoga graphql server + prisma server : multitenancy

Tags: graphql, multi-tenant, prisma, prisma-graphql

I'm setting up a backend env for multi-tenancy database using Prisma Server and Yoga GraphQL

To manage multi-tenancy, we choose to handle it by using the "env" (dev/stage/prod) of Prisma Server.
It's OK, Prisma server was not difficult to manage and now we have an endpoint for each tenant like: `http://localhost:4466/service/tenant/`

After that, it was easy to extract *.graphql from Prisma using graphql get-schema.

But now, the difficulty is: how to set up a GraphQL Server for as many as service I need and tenant ?

Based on different exmample / tuto / docs / ... I don't find the way to set up GraphQL Server in my index.js to say: listen on multiple URI and each URI have one prisma server connected.

Example, I need:

> GraphQL Server endpoint `http://localhost:4000/service-1/client-1/` can be only request `http://localhost:4466/service-1/client-1/`
>
> and for `client-2` (second tenant) `http://localhost:4000/service-1/client-2/` can be only request `http://localhost:4466/service-1/client-2/`

GraphQL Server seems can be started only one time per port (here 4000)

[EDIT] Here a code to illustrate https://github.com/mouchimotte/prisma-yoga-multitenancy

Comment: If you need more details do not hesitate ;)

Comment: I have just found this library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/prisma-multi-tenant). I hope it helps

Comment: thanks a lot @rma ! I think this package can be ma solution but I've stop dev using Prisma. I use Laravel instead, surely more longer to have the first query operational but more easy and structured ! More in adequateness with my product finally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @rma said in a comment, you can use the [prisma-multi-tenant](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prisma-multi-tenant) npm package to build a multi-tenant application.

You can read this article which explains how to make it work: https://medium.zenika.com/building-a-multi-tenant-application-with-prisma-11bf890304d6

Comment: Hello Errorname ! Like I've respond to @rma, I've stop dev using Prisma then pass to Laravel instead using "laravel tenancy" (hyn/multi-tenant) and folklore/graphql for the graphql part (who is based on webonyx package)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use a shared database strategy, meaning, one database with tenant ID column, you can use this package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-express-multitenant